# Access main activity method/components from broadcast receiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat

Basically I want my app to do something in background when headset is clicked twice. 
This code works only if I want info from debugger, what I'm trying to do is to call a method from main activity or click a button from main activity.

By example:
Once I catch a double click from headset, click a button from main activity.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

P.D.
It's my first app on android, so I would like some feedback about it.
My phone is Android 4.4.2 in case anyone tells me why I did not used MediaSession or anything else. (I know registerMediaButtonEventReceiver is deprecated)

**Receiver class:**

```
public class MediaReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int d = 0;

    public MediaReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction))
            return;
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    d++;

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (d == 1) {
                                Log.i("Info", "single click!");
                            }
                            // double click 
                            if (d == 2) {
                                Log.i("Info", "double click!");

                                //handleClick();  this method is inside MainActivity
                            }
                            d = 0;
                        }
                    };
                    if (d == 1) {
                        handler.postDelayed(r, 400);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

**onCreate MainActivity class:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        btnStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        btnStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_button);
        focus.setFormat("%s");

        manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "Proximity screen");

        mAudioManager =  (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(this, MediaReceiver.class);

        FillTaskScrollList();

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (headsetState == DISABLED_HEADSET_BUTTON) {
                    headsetState = ENABLED_HEADSET_BUTTON;
                    wl.acquire();
                    ...
                    focus.stop();
                    focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    btnStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_button);
                    mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
                } else {
                    headsetState = DISABLED_HEADSET_BUTTON;
                    wl.release();
                    ...
                    focus.stop();
                    btnStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_button);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already managed to solve it.

You have to use another **BroadcastReceiver** (inside the class you need) to catch a message from the **BroadcastReceiver** in another class. In my  case is **MediaReceiver** so I had to add this lines to send a message to the activity that I wanted to use.

**MediaReceive** onReceive()
You need to create a new Intent, I named "android.intent.MAIN" and you have to add the message to that intent (you can do that using putExtra[s] method).

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    Intent in = new Intent("android.intent.MAIN")
    in.putExtra("get_msg", "voice_rec");

    context.sendBroadcast(in);
    ...
}
```

**MainActivity**

I declared a new BroadcastReceiver and added onResume/onPause methods.
Created an IntentFilter using the same name I used for Intent created in MediaReceive class. Doing this gives you the capability to send message through BroadcastReceiver classes and Activities.  The rest of the code is what you want to do with that message, call a method or update a variable.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.MAIN");
    mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("get_msg");

            }
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mIntentReceiver);
}
```

Do not forget about register/unregister every BroadcastReceiver.

I hope it helps to anyone who is having a problem like I had.
Feel free to leave a comment.

Source: https://sites.google.com/site/zainozzaini/android/receive-sms-using-android-broadcastreceiver-inside-an-activity